# Issue Demoting Domain Controller

Tags: domain, domain-controller, rpc, active-directory

I am in the process of demoting a 2003r2 DC. I have set up a 2008r2 Server, set it up as a DC and moved all the roles over. Now I am ready to demote the older DC. When I run a dcpromo I am getting the error

" The Operation failed because: 
Active Directory could not transfer the remaining data in directory partition CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=[Domain],DC=com to domain controller server2008.domain.com

The RPC Server is unavailble"

I am in need of some insight. According to AD, the 2008 server is the primary server for all the roles. I can confirm this from both server.

Comment: It looks like a problem with replicating the Schema partition, not with the Shema role. How did you transfer the Schema Master FSMO role? There are 5 FSMO roles, did you transfer all 5?

Comment: Hi,

I followed the steps provided on these sites:
http://www.elmajdal.net/win2k8/Transferring_FSMO_Roles_in_Windows_Server_2008.aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324801

Comment: You should run the diagnostics to figure out why that data can't be transferred, and ensure replication is functioning properly.  If there's one thing in AD you especially don't want to be missing a piece of, it the Schema.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with Windows Firewall. I had to disable it for this to work.